# FLUSH TABLES don't work .

Tags: mysql, sql

WHy Flush Tables don't worK  ? I can INSERT /SELECT into TABLE.

```
mysql> FLUSH TABLES;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM big_table;
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|  1054155 |
+----------+
1 row in set (1.13 sec)
mysql> INSERT INTO exept VALUES(1);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)
```

I have all privileges.

When I use FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK I can't insert  but can select queries:

```
mysql> FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO exept VALUES(1);
ERROR 1223 (HY000): Can't execute the query because you have a conflicting read lock
mysql> SELECT * FROM exept;
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
+----+
1 row in set (0.03 sec)
```

How disabled INSERT/SELECT queries ?

Comment: what is your doubt as everything seems fine...as you have applied read lock so mysql is not allowing you to insert/update/delete but allow select.

Comment: is this a normal operation of these operators ?

Comment: yes flush means all tables data will be flush to disk, with read lock means change is not allowed while select is allowed.